# how to prove by induction the $ (1+x)^{n}>1+nx+nx^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

Prove by induction the formula

$ (1+x)^{n}>1+nx+nx^2$ for $x>0$ real number and $n\ge 3$

my try : multiply both sides by $(1+x)$

gives $ (1+x)^{n+1}>1+(n+1)x+(2n+nx)x^2$

have I done something wrong or what I do next?

$(2n+nx)$ must turn into $(n+1)$

Comment: You almost have  it. Note that for $n \geq 3$ then $(2n+nx) > (n+1)$ so $1 + (n+1) x + (2n+nx)x^2 > 1 + (n+1)x + (n+1)x^2$.

Comment: You just need to show that $2n + nx \geqslant n+1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. Note that $2n+x \geq 2n \geq n+1$.

Hence, the induction step becomes:

We have
$$(1+x)^n > 1 + nx + nx^2$$
Multiplying by $1+x$, we obtain
\begin{align}
(1+x)^{n+1} & = (1+x)^n (1+x)\\
& > (1+nx+nx^2)(1+x)\\
& = 1+ nx + nx^2 + x + nx^2 + nx^3\\
& = 1+(n+1)x + (n+n)x^2 + nx^3\\
& \geq 1+(n+1)x + (n+n)x^2 & (\because nx^3 \geq 0)\\
& \geq 1+(n+1)x + (n+1)x^2 & (\because n \geq 1)
\end{align}
which gives us the induction step.